# Posting Payment Data

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working on this script. It's a script for auto checkout on shopify based site like this (https://www.cityblueshop.com/products/kixx_asst). My problem is everything works fine, except submitting the payment data. For some reason it won't post the payment, even though I'm correctly extracting the id for cc_verify_id. If you guys can test it out and let me know what I'm doing wrong (stuck on this step for several days), then it will be really appreciated. You can input fake contact and credit card information. P.S. I'm new to programming so it might look messy. Thanks in advance for your help.

[EDIT]It looks like it's not submitting the data properly from paymentdata, but I still can't pinpoint where's the problem.

```
import requests, sys, time, re
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse


s = requests.session()

def UTCtoEST():
    current=datetime.now()
    return str(current) + ' EST'

home = 'cityblueshop'
###Get Session Id###
session = s.get('https://www.'+home+'.com/cart.js').json()
sessionID = session['token']
print('SessionID:', sessionID)

###ATC###
print(UTCtoEST(), 'Adding item....')
atcdata = {
    'id': '37431305678',
    'quantity': '1'
}
for atcurlRetry in range(1):
    atcURL = s.post('https://www.'+home+'.com/cart/add.js', data=atcdata, allow_redirects=True)
    match = re.findall('"quantity":1', atcURL.text)
    if match:
        print(UTCtoEST(), 'ATC successful....')
        break
    print(UTCtoEST(), 'Trying to ATC....')
    time.sleep(0)
else:
    print(UTCtoEST(), 'Could not ATC after ' + ' retries, therefore exiting the bot.')
    sys.exit(1)

###Going to Checkout Page###
for cartRetry in range(1):
    cartdata = {
        'updates[]': 1,
        'note': '',
        'checkout': 'Check Out'
    }
    atc = s.post('https://www.'+home+'.com/cart', data=cartdata, allow_redirects=True)
###Parsing URL###
    parse = urlparse(atc.url)
    storeID = parse.path.split('/')[1]
    checkoutID = parse.path.split('checkouts/')[1]
    print('Checkout Session Id:', checkoutID)
###Get Token###
    soup = BeautifulSoup(atc.text, 'lxml')
    input = soup.find_all('input')[2]
    auth_token = input.get('value')
    print('Auth_token:', auth_token)
###Get Contact info###
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Host': 'checkout.shopify.com',
        'Referer': 'https: //checkout.shopify.com/'+storeID+'/checkouts/'+checkoutID+'?step=contact_information',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36'
    }
    qs = {
        'utf8': '✓',
        '_method': 'patch',
        'authenticity_token': auth_token,
        'previous_step': 'contact_information',
        'checkout[email]': 'email',
        'checkout[shipping_address][first_name]': 'First',
        'checkout[shipping_address][last_name]': 'Last',
        'checkout[shipping_address][company]': '',
        'checkout[shipping_address][address1]': 'Address 1',
        'checkout[shipping_address][address2]': '',
        'checkout[shipping_address][city]': 'City',
        'checkout[shipping_address][country]': 'United States',
        'checkout[shipping_address][province]': '',
        'checkout[shipping_address][province]': '',
        'checkout[shipping_address][province]': 'New York',
        'checkout[shipping_address][zip]': 'Zip',
        'checkout[shipping_address][phone]': 'Phone',
        'checkout[remember_me]': '',
        'checkout[remember_me]': '0',
        'checkout[client_details][browser_width]': '979',
        'checkout[client_details][browser_height]': '631',
        'checkout[client_details][javascript_enabled]': '1',
        'step': 'contact_information'
    }
    GETcontact = s.get(atc.url, data=qs, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)

###Post Contact Info###
    headers1 = {
        'Origin': 'https://checkout.shopify.com',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Referer': 'https://checkout.shopify.com/'+storeID+'/checkouts/'+checkoutID,
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36'
    }
    formData = {
        'utf8': '✓',
        '_method': 'patch',
        'authenticity_token': auth_token,
        'button': '',
        'checkout[email]': 'Email',
        'checkout[shipping_address][first_name]': 'First',
        'checkout[shipping_address][last_name]': 'Last',
        'checkout[shipping_address][company]': '',
        'checkout[shipping_address][address1]': 'Address 1',
        'checkout[shipping_address][address2]': '',
        'checkout[shipping_address][city]': 'City',
        'checkout[shipping_address][country]': 'United States',
        'checkout[shipping_address][province]': 'New York',
        'checkout[shipping_address][zip]': 'Zip',
        'checkout[shipping_address][phone]': 'Phone',
        'checkout[remember_me]': '0',
        'checkout[client_details][browser_width]': '979',
        'checkout[client_details][browser_height]': '631',
        'checkout[client_details][javascript_enabled]': '1',
        'previous_step': 'contact_information',
        'step': 'shipping_method'
    }
    POSTcontact = s.post(atc.url, data=formData, headers=headers1, allow_redirects=True)
    ###Parsing Shipping Method###
    soup = BeautifulSoup(POSTcontact.text, 'html.parser')
    shipping = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'radio-wrapper'})
    shipping_method = ship.get('data-shipping-method')

###Submitting Shipping Data###
    headers2 = {
        'Origin': 'https://checkout.shopify.com',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Referer': 'https://checkout.shopify.com/'+storeID+'/checkouts/'+checkoutID,
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36'
    }
    ShipformData = {
        'utf8': '✓',
        '_method': 'patch',
        'authenticity_token': auth_token,
        'previous_step': 'shipping_method',
        'step': 'payment_method',
        'checkout[shipping_rate][id]': shipping_method,
        'button': '',
        'checkout[client_details][browser_width]': '1280',
        'checkout[client_details][browser_height]': '368',
        'checkout[client_details][javascript_enabled]': '1'
    }
    shippingmethod = s.post(atc.url, data=ShipformData, headers=headers2, allow_redirects=True)
    ###Parsing payment_gateaway###
    soup = BeautifulSoup(shippingmethod.text, 'html.parser')
    ul = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'radio-wrapper content-box__row '})
    payment_gateaway = ul.get('data-select-gateway')

###submitting payment info###
    CCheaders = {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Origin': 'https://checkout.shopifycs.com',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Host': 'elb.deposit.shopifycs.com',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Referer': 'https://checkout.shopifycs.com/number?identifier='+checkoutID+'&location=3A%2F%2Fcheckout.shopify.com%2F'+storeID+'%2Fcheckouts%2F'+checkoutID+'%3Fpreviousstep%3Dshipping_method%26step%3Dpayment_method',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36'
    }
    ccinfo = {
        'number': "0000 0000 0000 0000",
        'name': "First Last",
        'month': 5,
        'year': 2020,
        'verification_value': "000"
    }
    creditcard = s.post('https://elb.deposit.shopifycs.com/sessions', json=ccinfo, headers=CCheaders, allow_redirects=True)
    cc_verify = creditcard.json()
    cc_verify_id = cc_verify['id']

###submitting credit card info##
    paymentheaders = {
        'Origin': 'https://checkout.shopify.com',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Referer': 'https://checkout.shopify.com/'+storeID+'/checkouts/'+checkoutID,
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.98 Safari/537.36'
    }
    paymentdata = {
        '_method': 'patch',
        'authenticity_token': auth_token,
        'checkout[buyer_accepts_marketing]': '1',
        'checkout[client_details][browser_height]': '979',
        'checkout[client_details][browser_width]': '631',
        'checkout[client_details][javascript_enabled]': '1',
        'checkout[credit_card][vault]': 'false',
        'checkout[different_billing_address]': 'false',
        'checkout[payment_gateway]': payment_gateaway,
        'checkout[total_price]': '1199',
        'complete': '1',
        'previous_step': 'payment_method',
        's': cc_verify_id,
        'step': '',
        'utf8': '✓'
      }
    submitpayment = s.post(atc.url, data=paymentdata, headers=paymentheaders, allow_redirects=True)
    print(UTCtoEST(), submitpayment.status_code, submitpayment.url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but this isn't a proper key if you are trying to post JSON..

```
'checkout[total_price]': '1199',
```

You need to rewrite as

```
'checkout' : {
    'total_price': '1199',
}
```

And you need to apply this solution to all the other values in that format

For example

```
 'checkout' : {
    'remember_me' : '', 
    'shipping_address' : { 
        'first_name': 'First',
        "last_name': 'Last'
```

And I think you can use Python False value instead of the string `' false'`, but that depends on the API

Comment: Hi, the data is not in JSON, but it's in >Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded< The only JSON payload is the creditcard section, and I already used json=ccinfo for that section of the payload.

Comment: Well, still, it's a Python dictionary in your code, so what happens when you try this?

Comment: It's just redirecting me back to checkout page. If the data was posted correctly, it would had response code of 302, and then it should redirect me to success page, but it doesn't. My form data for contact information and shipping posted just fine. It's this payment data won't post at all, and I have spent countless of hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: Have you used another tool like Postman to see if you are able to submit data?

Comment: No, I have not. But I will take a look at it now.

Comment: could not use postman because it does not let me do GET with form data.

Comment: No tool should let you do that. A GET request has no HTTP body

Comment: So I tried posting data for contact information on Postman, and seems like its not sticking. But, on my script it seems to be there. If you get a chance can you please test it out for me?